# Not able to access Tomcat from another machine in LAN

Tags: tomcat

I have two web applications running under Apache HTTP server and these applications use ports 8080 and 100. Recently i have installed Apache Tomcat 7.0.42 and i have changed the port number in server.xml from 8080 to 9999 as another application under Apache HTTP Server is already using 8080.

I am able to access Tomcat from the local machine using localhost:9999 and with IP Address:9999. But i am not able to access the Tomcat sever using IP Address:9999 from another machine in the network.

I could able to access the other application running on ports 8080 and 100 from another machine.

To check if there is any port issue, i stopped the application which is using 8080 and given the same port to Tomcat but still Tomcat is not accesible from another machine. So it is evident that it is not a port issue.

I think Tomcat is not accepting remote requests and i assume i need to do some changes in the server.xml file to enable the remote access. Please help me in solving this issue.

Regards
Praveen
SCM Consultant

Comment: Praveen this question would be better placed on ServerFault.com. Also it would help your cause if you named the OS where Tomcat was running and the OS from which you are trying to connect, so that appropriate troubleshooting measures can be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The server that you are running on may be blocking traffic on 9999 at the os/firewall level.  If you are on linux check iptables to make sure 9999 is open.

(as root) # iptables -L -n -v

Comment: I tried using port 8080 for Tomcat and i am not able access from another machine. As i mentioned in my initial thread, port 8080 is working for other application under Apache HTTP server and when i tried using the same port (after stopping the application using 8080 and assigning 8080 to tomcat) for Tomcat, it is not working. So problem is not with port number or firewall.

Comment: Server OS where Tomcat is running is Win 2008 Server R2. Client is Windows 7.